# Printing Text before redirecting to another link

Tags: java, servlets

I want to print some text before redirecting my response to google search link..but I am unable to print it.My code for redirecting servlet is as below:

```
package sendredirect;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SendRedirectServlet extends HttpServlet {

    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {


        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello World");
        
        try {
            
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        
        String textToSearch = req.getParameter("textToGoogle");
        
        resp.sendRedirect("https://www.google.com/search?q="+ textToSearch);  
        
        out.close();
        
    }
    

}
```

Why I couldn't get the output from the code `out.println("Hello World");` in my browser before redirecting to google search .

My `index.html` file is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Send Redirect Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="sr" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="textToGoogle"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Google It!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my `web.xml` file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ServletSendRedirect</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SR</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>sendredirect.SendRedirectServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  
  
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SR</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/sr</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendRedirect` is sending a response code like 302 or 304 (I assume 302 Temporary Redirect) to the browser and a `Location` header telling the client where to go instead. This is then handled transparently by the browser, without it ever having to display anything.

To see the HTTP response for yourself use `curl -v http://yourendpoint`, or use [Postman](https://www.postman.com) if you prefer a browser based tool. Or you can look at the request/response in your browser dev tools, under the network tab (you might have to find an option that doesn't clear the inpector history on page load).

Alternatively you would pass the redirect url to the page and do the redirect later with javascript.

You could respond with something like this, to display the page and redirect after 3 seconds:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    Hello there, redirecting soon
    <script type="application/javascript">
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/search?q=dogs";
      }, 3000); 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

> Why couldn't I print, If i close the PrintWriter after redirecting it
> to google link?

I'll start from the other direction first, flushing/closing before calling `sendRedirect`.

When you call `out.println("Hello World");`, tomcat writes "Hello World" to an OutputBuffer [here](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/327fb6ff6de541e3d3e321a434d13585cea07875/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/CoyoteWriter.java#L163), it is stored in memory until it is flushed. At this point you could still change the response code using something like `resp.setStatus(201);` because nothing has been sent back to the client.

As soon as you flush the Writer with `out.flush()`, or `out.close()` Tomcat has to pick what Headers to write to the HTTP response, as they must come before the body. Like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date: Mon, 14 Jun 2021 02:05:46 GMT

Hello World
```

See [here](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/327fb6ff6de541e3d3e321a434d13585cea07875/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/OutputBuffer.java#L292), on the first flush of the output buffer. It sends headers, which then sets the [response to committed](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9.0.48/java/org/apache/coyote/Response.java#L441).

This is when the response is `committed` as in your stack trace. You cannot change the headers or status code at this point. So there is no going back and changing to a 302.

When you call `sendRedirect` after the first flush then it [fails with error](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/327fb6ff6de541e3d3e321a434d13585cea07875/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Response.java#L1352) if the response is committed for the above reason.

If you go the other way and print to the in-memory buffer, do not flush and then call `sendRedirect`, one of the first things it does is [reset the output buffer](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/327fb6ff6de541e3d3e321a434d13585cea07875/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Response.java#L1362). Discarding your string before it proceeds to [send the status code and Location header](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/327fb6ff6de541e3d3e321a434d13585cea07875/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Response.java#L1374).

Comment: That's cool but I don't want to use javascript..I am already making the code sleep by `Thread.sleep(5000);` so before redirecting to google search why it is not showing `"Hello World"`? i just want to know what's wrong in the code or is it such that while using redirecting we can't print any output?

Comment: Ah, cool, what container are you using so I could have a play with it? Tomcat, jetty, etc?

I'd guess it has buffered your response and not sent it yet when you put it to sleep. What happens if you flush the PrintWriter before sleep? Again using postman or curl will help diagnose this.

Comment: when i close the PrintWriter by `out.close()` before redirecting or before sleep..Then I got `Hello World` as output in browser but then it doesn't redirect to google search link. An shows the error :SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SR] in context with path [/ServletSendRedirect] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed.                                                                                                       PS. I am using `Apache Tomcat 9`

Comment: Yep, they are incompatible. Once you've closed the response it would have flushed a full 200 HTTP response with body. So it is no longer possible after that to send the 302 redirect.

Comment: Cool..now back to original question.Why couldn't I print, If i close the PrintWriter after redirecting it to google link?I have also updated my full code stack ..Please check it too..